# Computer stopped being discovered by other devices on network

Tags: home-networking, file-sharing

My problem is rather strange and one I haven't come across before.

Today, out of the blue, my PC stopped being discovered by other devices
 on the home network; the Plex media server and Unified Remote servers running on the computer are being discovered by their respective apps just fine, but the stopped showing up under network devices in apps like ES File Explorer and Network File Explorer
 for file-sharing purposes.

The computer is on a wired connection to the router while the other
 devices are connected through wifi. When I initially switched to a wifi connection on the computer with the help of a Wireless N USB Adapter, the computer popped back up under network devices, but even that has stopped working now.

I've gone through the basics, restarted everything, did a network reset,
 did a factory reset on the router, uninstalled and reinstalled Ethernet drivers, flushed IP routes restarted and the issue hasn't gone away.
Deleting network profile entries from the registry and restarting
 worked to get lan discovery on Wifi network active again but then I did something else and it went away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, just to be clear here, this PC that other devices cannot discover is the same PC hosting the "Plex media server and Unified Remote servers" too, correct? Is this a Windows OS deal and have you confirmed the network adapter interface being used is not in an "unidentified" state?

Comment: wifi and wired access may have isolation mode on.  something that accesses via wifi might be in isolation mode while the only pc connected via wired isn't.  I bet if you added the wifi machines to wired you will see them.

Comment: You don't indicate what OS you are using